# Which for loops is totally correct for swapping two elements in C?

Tags: c

Both of them can run, but I think their logic are not same.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[j])
        {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
        {
            temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Which one is totally correct for swapping two elements in C?

Comment: There logic is not the same, and neither is "totally correct for swapping two elements", which is basically nonsense. Each loop performs the same end-goal: sort the sequence. It just does it in two different ways. The former is a hybrid selection sort, the latter is a bubble sort. Both use element-swaps (plural) to accomplish that goal.

Comment: Does it make sense to swap elemens having the same index?

Answer (score -1):

Logic for swapping is same in both the codes btw these codes does sorting. Swapping was just a step in sorting. Alternatively you can try

```
num1 = num1 ^ num2; //Using XOR operator
num2 = num1 ^ num2;
num1 = num1 ^ num2;

num1 = num1 + num2; //Using Add & Sub operator
num2 = num1 - num2;
num1 = num1 - num2;

num1 = num1 * num2; //Using Multiply & Divide operator
num2 = num1 / num2;
num1 = num1 / num2;
```